# Rails 7: Change association of nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## The setup

I have two models: `Language` and `LanguageCode` and they look as follows:

One language can have multiple language codes.

```rb
class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :language_codes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :language_codes, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :reject_empty

  def reject_empty(attributes)
    attributes['id'].blank?
  end
end

class LanguageCode < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :language, optional: true
end
```

`LanguageCode`s get created independently of `Language`s. For example, the code `en_us` should be assigned to `English`, and so on. In contrast to the guides, a `LanguageCode` can exist outside of a `Language` and can also change the association, being assigned to another language.

I use a nested for with a `collection_select` which shows me all available `LanguageCodes`, namely those that haven't been assigned and those that have already been assigned. This works well.

The controllers update method looks as follows:

```rb
class LanguagesController < BaseController
  # Save updates to database.
  def update
    # Find language by id, code omitted
    lang = params.require(:language).permit(:label, language_codes_attributes: [:id, :_destroy])
    @language.update(lang)

    # The rest of the method
    # ...
  end
end
```

## The problem

Whenever I select a language from the dropdown, the `@language.update` fails. The reason is that it tries to perform a lookup based on `:id` and `:language_id`, where the latter is not set. This is because the code is not yet associated with the language, thus the `belongs_to` id is not set in the database.

The **question** I have is: Is it possible to use nested attributes in this way? Or is their only purpose to have fixed associations, as in: A `Language` has a `Code` and the code always belongs to the same language?

## The attempted solution

My solution is quite simple: In the controller, read all nested attributes on `update`, update each LanguageCode by id and set the belongs_to manually. This can look something like this and it should work fine:

```rb
def update
  @language = Language.find(params[:id])
  params[:language][:language_codes_attributes].each do |attr|
    LanguageCode.find(attr[:id]).update(language: @language)
  end

  # Rest of the method
end
```

Comment: Hmm, this is a pretty hard to answer question as you're going straight into the nitty gritty without properly describing how the feature should actually work from the users POV. Then there is all the misconceptions - `nested_attributes` is really just a feature that lets you pass attributes to update/create its children. You're not even using it at all here since you're basically clobbering the functionality. There is no such thing as "fixed" assocations - as long as the column is changable by Rails any assocation can be re-assigned.

Comment: Nested attributes can be used to change any attribute. Including the "parent id". It's not really something thats commonly done though.

Comment: Your proposed solution is also very inefficient - you could simply do `LanguageCode.where(id: 'ids').update_all(language_id: @language.id)` and do a single query instead of *n* - but you still need to handle what happens when users unselect an existing assocation. Do you want to nullify the language id column?

Comment: @max thank you, that's a good observation, I will change this implementation. I now opted to process the nested attributes manually and let the update method just deal with the `Language` object. I will try out the solution below since this seems to be closest to what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're doing in your form with that collection_select. But for cases like this there is `language_code_ids` method:

```rb
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :language_code_ids, LanguageCode.all, :id, :code %>
```

Make sure to permit it: `.permit(language_code_ids: [])`. Everything should just work by itself. `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is not needed for this.

```rb
>> Language.first.language_code_ids
  Language Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "languages".* FROM "languages" ORDER BY "languages"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  LanguageCode Pluck (0.1ms)  SELECT "language_codes"."id" FROM "language_codes" WHERE "language_codes"."language_id" = ?  [["language_id", 1]]
=> [3]

>> Language.first.language_code_ids = [1,2]
  Language Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "languages".* FROM "languages" ORDER BY "languages"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  LanguageCode Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "language_codes".* FROM "language_codes" WHERE "language_codes"."id" IN (?, ?)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2]]
  LanguageCode Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "language_codes".* FROM "language_codes" WHERE "language_codes"."language_id" = ?  [["language_id", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  LanguageCode Update All (0.2ms)  UPDATE "language_codes" SET "language_id" = ? WHERE "language_codes"."language_id" = ? AND "language_codes"."id" = ?  [["language_id", nil], ["language_id", 1], ["id", 3]]
  LanguageCode Update (0.1ms)  UPDATE "language_codes" SET "language_id" = ? WHERE "language_codes"."id" = ?  [["language_id", 1], ["id", 1]]
  LanguageCode Update (0.1ms)  UPDATE "language_codes" SET "language_id" = ? WHERE "language_codes"."id" = ?  [["language_id", 1], ["id", 2]]
  TRANSACTION (6.5ms)  commit transaction
=> [1, 2]
```

Only updates, no deletions.

Comment: One potential problem here is that when you "unassign" a language code Rails will actually delete the row. I think the indended behavior is that the `language_id` should be set to nil.

Comment: @max seem to work. i think actual deletions happen only for join tables.

Comment: That is a very interesting solution. I will try it out soon, thank you.